# what php extension are needed to run this php script?

Tags: php, curl, sftp

```
<?php

// ftp URL to file
$url = 'sftp site';

// init curl session with FTP address
$ch = curl_init($url);

// specify a callback function for reading data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'readCallback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);

// send download headers for client
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="backup.tar.bz2"');

// execute request, our read callback will be called when data is available
curl_exec($ch);


// read callback function, takes 3 params, the curl handle, the stream to read from and the maximum number of bytes to read    
function readCallback($curl, $stream, $maxRead)
{
// read the data from the ftp stream
$read = fgets($stream, $maxRead);

// echo the contents just read to the client which contributes to their total download
echo $read;

// return the read data so the function continues to operate
return $read;
}
```

when i just install php-curl, libcurl and curl, the script returns and blank file
but, when i install everything that have on yum repo

```
yum install php-*
```

everything works fine

Comment: Btw, you don't echo anything here, what do you expect?

Comment: @mulder no error logs

Comment: this script is not to echo anything. as i say, when i install everything, the script works just fine.

Comment: SO, what's the problem then?

Comment: I agree with @u_mulder you need to enable error reporting / error logging. That should help you identify the extension required.

Answer (score 0):

PHP curl extension due to using curl functions.

Comment: when i just install php-curl, libcurl and curl, the script returns an blank file